# Erro ao fazer consulta com between em campo datetime

Tags: sql-server

Estou tentando fazer um between mas não sei como proceder.

```
where cliente.id = (select usuario.idCliente from usuario where usuario.login = 'julio') and
(cast(os.dataHora as date) between  '2016-09-08' and '2013-10-29')
```

ou

where cliente.id = (select usuario.idCliente from usuario where usuario.login = 'julio') and
(os.dataHora between  '2016-09-08' and '2013-10-29')

Erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute na sua base de dados:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
```

O correto é você mudar a linguagem do seu banco, assim funcionará no no padrão 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Caso queira utilizar da forma como está, o formato é:

```
yyyy-dd-mm hh:mi:ss.ms
```

Para converter uma `String` para data você pode utilizar qualquer um dos seguintes comandos:

```
cast('2016-11-07' as date);
```

ou

```
convert(date, '2016-11-07');
```

Comment: Eu tenho uma outra aplicação antiga que futuramente vai morrer mas devo manter essa aplicação funcionando.
Vc acha que fazendo isso, vai dar ruim na aplicação antiga?
A nova ainda não está pronta.

Comment: kkk. Que coisa mais estranha.
Agora eu quero ver no PHP. Pelo jeito eu vou ter trabalho. Obr.

Comment: Como eu faço a conversão usando convert ou cast?

Comment: Como eu não pude usar o set format ymd, eu coloquei o convert sendo a melhor resposta.
Obrigado de qualquer forma. Eu estava tentando desde ontem.

Comment: testado com convert e cast. Desculpa ae.

Answer (score 1):

Funcionou usando **CONVERT**
where os.dataHora between CONVERT(datetime, '01-08-2016', 105) and CONVERT(datetime, '30-10-2016', 105)

Comment: Fabrício, você usou a opção correta, que é o uso da função Convert para indicar ao SQL Server qual é o formato em que a data é fornecida. É a forma mais segura e que garante que o aplicativo rodará corretamente, qualquer que seja a configuração de LANGUAGE do servidor.